# Is it possible to selectively route traffic via NAT GW (to specific external IP) from public subnet in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, kubernetes, sip, nat

I am using a 3rd party PSTN Gateway service which requires my IP be whitelisted, and my infrastructure is hosted in AWS (self managed kubernetes).

My cluster has two subnets public & private. all nodes in private subnet uses NAT GW to reach the web. while nodes in public subnet has public IP assigned so they directly reach web via internet gateway.

I want all data going to PSTN gateway to go through NAT GW while any other traffic be using internet gateway.

Since my nodes in public can scale up/down, I can not whitelist these node IP so I prefer to route the traffic through NAT gateway.

In route table of public subnet, I have added rule to route data going to PSTN GW be routed via NAT GW. but this doesn't seem to work. when I add this rule, the traffic from my public node doesn't reach PSTN GW. I do not understand why it wont work.

can anybody shed some light as to why it is not working and what is the right course to achieve what I intend to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Steps look file. Did you white list the NATGW ElasIP in the PSTN? Also look at the NATGW troubleshooting documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: If you want to use NAT gateway, your instances should be in private subnet.

Comment: @Marcin, in my usecase the VM is in public subnet. can you recommend an approach to route traffic via NAT GW?

Comment: @PraveenSripati NAT IP is whitelisted for sure. I have verified by sending traffic via NAT from private node and PSTN GW accepted the request. I want to send requests to PSTN GW from NAT gateway and receive responses at public IP of ec2 instance.

Comment: PSTN GW is sending the responses blindly to the IP:Port in VIA header of SIP INVITE. so I am trying to route the INVITE via NAT GW and set public IP/Port in VIA header of ec2  instance so PSTN GW can send response at public IP of the node.

Comment: To use NAT instance must be in private subnet. There is no other way.